# Microsoft Word 2003 - How to create an enormous work area/paper size - bigger than A3?

Tags: microsoft-word, paper, mind-mapping

I am using MS Word 2003 to create a mindmap. My current settings are A3 but that is getting too small.

How do get a paper size of e.g. 4 times the area of an A3?

PS
I am not looking to ever print the mindmap so being able to print the map is not necessary.

Comment: Is there anything that is preventing you from setting it like this in the page setup?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the **Page Layout** tab
2. Press the little arrow at the bottom right of the **Page Setup**
   area.
3. Click on the **Paper** tab on the dialog box that pops up.
4. Enter in your desired paper size into the **Width** and **Height**
   boxes.

Note that Microsoft Word limits either dimension of a page to around 56cm so I'm afraid you will not be able to get four times the area of an A3 page, but you will be able to get about half that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if it is possible to do in Word 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Yes the steps above work in Word 2007 and Word 2010 as well.